# System.OutOfMemoryException when getting string array from c++ on c#

Tags: c#, c++, exception, dll, interop

My C++ function

```
    void FillArray(wchar_t** arr)
    {
         // some code
         for(i= 0;i<end;++i)
         {
             wcsncpy(arr[i],InforArray[i],MaxLength);
             count++;
         } 
     }
```

My C# signature is

```
[DllImport("Native.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,EntryPoint = "FillArray")]
        internal static extern void FillArray(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] 
            IntPtr[] OutBuff);
```

And the C# code itself:

```
int maxLen = 256;


int count = GetPropertyCount(ref eData);
IntPtr[] buffer = new IntPtr[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
     buffer[i] = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(maxLen);

FillArray(buffer);

string[] output = new string[count];

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
      output[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(buffer[i]); 
      Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer[i]);
}
```

The data is populated with no problems in c++ loop, but when  exiting FillArray I got "An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred"

Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you changed the calling convention to match the default calling convention of C++?  What line exactly is cause the OutOfMemoryException?

Comment: How much memory are you trying to allocate? Does it work if you limit it to something small like a few bytes?

Comment: I tried  CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl with no luck. I allocate small amount of memory like 7*256 array and have 8 GB of memory ... it is related somehow to marshaling the results back as the program crashed when it switch back to c#

Comment: @SharonL - I do hope you did keep where you defined the calling convention ( just good code ).

Comment: You are helping too much.  Remove the [MarshalAs] attribute so that the pinvoke marshaller doesn't try to release the strings.  Not so sure why that causes OOM.

Comment: I removed it but still OOM thrown with STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN

Comment: if wchar is > 1 byte, then MaxLen=256 bytes is not enough for 256 wchar.

Comment: What does the `GetPropertyCount` function do (assuming its not part of the .NET framework, since I can't find it on the MSDN as a pure function)?  Which line is the exception being thrown at?

Answer (score 2):

Given the nature of the exception you are encountering the program is failing attempting to allocate memory, which is occuring in two spots in your example code `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` and `Marshal.PtrToStringUni()`. So unless `GetPropertyCount()` is returning `Int.MaxValue` somehow, the program is likely failing because [wcsncpy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wcsncpy.html) does not null terminate the copied string. So the call to `Marshal.PtrToStringUni()` is allocating all your machine's memory attempting to determine where the copied strings actually end. Try using the [PtrToStringUni](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyf0tzy4.aspx) API that allows you to provide the number of characters to copy.